# Is there a way in pg-promise to trigger an inner transaction that won't affect the outer transaction?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, transactions, pg-promise

In `pg-promise` I have a situation in which I need to trigger an inner transaction that can roll back if needed that won't cause the calling transaction to be rolled back when it errors:

```
var db = pgp()(connection);
db.task( function (tk){
  tk.method(/* Logic used to decide if I need to continue */)
  .then( function(data){
    if (!data) return;
    tk.tx( function*(tx){
      // Somewhere in here I need to fire another transaction that I don't care if it fails
      // but I need things to roll back inside of it should it fail
      // without cause this tx to fail
    })
  })
})
```

Everything I've tried so far has just caused the outer transaction (`tx`) to rollback if the inner transaction fails instead of the inner transaction rolling back and the outer transaction continuing with the logic that would come after. Is there a reliable way to cause an inner transaction that WON'T cause `tx` to rollback if the child transaction fails?

As an additional: this also fails when I attempt to use a `Bluebird` `Promise.some(tx1, tx2)` as either failing causes `tx` to roll back and the other tx# to fail and rollback as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything within [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), as the name implies, built on promises, including the transaction logic, so the answer you are looking for is purely promise-related:

*If you do not want the result of an inner promise to affect the outer promise, you simply do not chain that inner promise to the parent, you process/handle it locally instead.*

For your transaction this means that instead of this:

```
tk.tx(function * (t1) {
    return yield t1.tx(function * (t2))
       // chained inner transaction (savepoint)
    });
}).then(data=>{}).catch(error=>{});
```

you would be doing this:

```
tk.tx(function * (t1) {
    t1.tx(function * (t2))
        // unchained/localized inner transaction (savepoint)
    }).then(data=>{}).catch(error=>{});
}).then(data=>{}).catch(error=>{});
```

i.e. you process the result from the inner transaction locally, without chaining it to the parent.

Comment: I'm curious then if it's because we're locked into an older version of pg-promise. I'll go check the commit history on github and possible solutions from there.

Comment: @RobertMennell Could be that you are mixing up ES6 generators in the midst, those can be tricky, easy to make a mistake where you should or should not use `yield` ;)

Comment: thanks for pointing that out! Didn't think of that, but it'll be helpful for everyone who comes after me